# User input not binding from $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

Just getting started with Angular and I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure out how to bind data from a new search through a service. I had the search working before with the following code before using a service:

SearchController.js

```js
function SearchController($scope, $http){

  $scope.search = ""


  $scope.getGames = function (){
    return $http.get("https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/games/?fields=name%2Crating%2Ccover%2Curl%2Csummary%2Cfirst_release_date&limit=50&offset=0&order=release_dates.date%3Aasc&search=" + $scope.search, {"headers": {
        "x-mashape-key": "KEY",
         "accept": "application/json",
       }
     })
      .success(function(resp){
        $scope.games = resp

      })
      .error(function(data){
        console.log(data)
      })

  }

  $scope.getGames()

};

SearchController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http']

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SearchController',SearchController)
```

```html
search.html

<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="SearchController">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <h1>Search for Game</h1>
      <form name="form">
        <input name="search" ng-model="search" ng-change="getGames()"
               ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" placeholder="Type Game"
               minlength="3"
               required="required" />
               <div ng-messages="form.search.$error" ng-if="form.search.$touched">
                 <div ng-message="required">Please type a game to search.</div>
                 <div ng-message="minlength">3 characters required</div>
               </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row fix-heights">
      <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="game in games | filter: search" class="row-eq-height">
        <br>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="pull-left" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/{{ game.cover.cloudinary_id }}.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <p>Title: <a href="{{game.url}}">{{ game.name }}</a></p>
            <p>Release Date: {{ game.first_release_date | date:'mediumDate'}}
            <p>Short Description: {{ game.summary }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

So my first attempt was successful but when I tried to move the code to a service I am unable to automatically update and bind the data from the new search. I've tried to use $scope.$watch and I can see the url change in the console but the results do not populate in my search.html. Below are the new changes.

```js
function SearchController($scope, $http, GetGameService){


  $scope.search = ""

  search = $scope.search

  GetGameService.getGames(search)
      .success(function(resp){
        $scope.games = resp
        console.log(resp)
      })
      .error(function(data){
        console.log(data)
      })

  $scope.$watch('search', function(){
    search = $scope.search
    GetGameService.getGames(search)
  })
};

SearchController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'GetGameService']

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('SearchController',SearchController)


/////////GetGameService.js

function GetGameService($http){
  this.getGames = function(search) {
    return $http.get("https://igdbcom-internet-game-database-v1.p.mashape.com/games/?fields=name%2Crating%2Ccover%2Curl%2Csummary%2Cfirst_release_date&limit=50&offset=0&order=release_dates.date%3Aasc&search=" + search, {"headers": {
      "x-mashape-key": "KEY",
       "accept": "application/json",
     }
   })
 }
}

GetGameService.$inject = ["$http"]

angular
  .module('app')
  .service("GetGameService", GetGameService);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="SearchController">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
      <h1>Search for Game</h1>
      <form name="form">
        <input name="search" ng-model="search" 
               ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}" placeholder="Type Game"
               minlength="3"
               required="required" />
               <div ng-messages="form.search.$error" ng-if="form.search.$touched">
                 <div ng-message="required">Please type a game to search.</div>
                 <div ng-message="minlength">3 characters required</div>
               </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row fix-heights">
      <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="game in games | filter: search" class="row-eq-height">
        <br>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <img class="pull-left" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/igdb/image/upload/t_thumb/{{ game.cover.cloudinary_id }}.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="media-body">
            <p>Title: <a href="{{game.url}}">{{ game.name }}</a></p>
            <p>Release Date: {{ game.first_release_date | date:'mediumDate'}}
            <p>Short Description: {{ game.summary }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Apologies for any wrong format and many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The primary error is you are missing the `$scope.games` assign inside your `$watch`

I'm not sure whether you really want to call `getGames` on init, or intend to use it as a function.

The controller can be reorganized to reduce code replication

```
function SearchController($scope, $http, GetGameService){

  $scope.search = ""

  // getGames(); // if you need to call on init, call here

  $scope.$watch('search', function(){
    getGames();
  })

  function getGames() {
    return GetGameService.getGames($scope.search)
      .then(function(resp){ // it's better to use .then than .success
        $scope.games = resp
        console.log(resp)

      }, function(data){
        console.log(data)
      })
  }
};
```

Comment: Completely overlooked that. Made the changes and it's working perfectly! Thank you for clearing my headache along with it.